# How to split path up to certain hierarchy

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, regex-negation

I want to use Perl to split the  path

```
funit/pipe/str/str32/gt/split
```

up to

```
funit/pipe/str/str32/gt
```

using a regular expression.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
Please show your own coding attempts.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code (if you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably the wrong place to be asking this question).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want the path to the parent directory; is that right? I wouldn't call it "splitting" the path

Is the restriction on using a regex pattern a genuine one, or did you just think it would be the best method?

Here's a program that uses `Path::Tiny` to do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;

my $path = Path::Tiny->new('funit/pipe/str/str32/gt/split');

say $path;
say $path->parent;
```

#### output

```
funit/pipe/str/str32/gt/split
funit/pipe/str/str32/gt
```

Comment: This doesn't look like regex, I do have same question however I need to use it to configure nginx